# Clase Modelo no encontrada en Laravel con Drupal

Tags: php, laravel, drupal

Estoy haciendo unas prácticas de empresas y mi tutor de prácticas me pide realizar un sitio web con Drupal 8 y que utilice Laravel para realizar las consultas. He buscado y rebuscado por internet y no encuentro la manera de realizar dicha tarea. Solo he encontrado redirigir el `.htaccess` al `index.html` de Laravel.

Mi mayor problema ahora mismo es que estoy trabajando en un subdominio de un servidor remoto, `sin acceso ssh`, solo a través de panel de gestión `Plesk`. Tengo la siguiente estructura de archivos en mi subdominio:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se ve en la imagen, existe una carpeta Laravel donde he alojado los ficheros de un proyecto `"virgen"`. Es decir, simplemente es la estructura de directorios Laravel para poder utilizarla como API.
De esta manera, me he creado una BBDD en local que he conectado través del fichero `.env` de Laravel.

Creada la BBDD y una tabla, me dispongo a consultar y extraer datos de una tabla. He creado el siguiente modelo, controlador y vista para ello:

`MODELO`

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Candidato extends Model
{
   protected $table = 'candidatos';
}

?>
```

`CONTROLADOR`

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Models\Candidato;

Route::get('/', function () {


$candidatos = Candidato::all();
return view('candidatos.index')->with('candidatos', $candidatos);

});
```

`VISTA`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Candidatos</title>
</head>
<body>
    
    <table style="width: 100%">

    <tr>
        <td>Usuario</td>
        <td>Nombre y apellidos</td>
        <td>Fecha de nacimiento</td>
        <td>Sexo</td>
        <td>Email</td>
        <td>Telefono</td>
        <td>Direccion</td>
        <td>Municipio</td>
        <td>Provincia</td>
        <td>Pais</td>
        <td>Formacion</td>
        <td>Intereses</td>
    </tr>

        @foreach ($candidatos as $candidato)
        
            <tr>
                <td>$candidato->usuario</td>
                <td>$candidato->nombre_apellidos</td>
                <td>$candidato->fecha_nacimiento</td>
                <td>$candidato->sexo</td>
                <td>$candidato->email</td>
                <td>$candidato->telefono</td>
                <td>$candidato->direccion</td>
                <td>$candidato->municipio</td>
                <td>$candidato->provincia</td>
                <td>$candidato->pais</td>
                <td>$candidato->formacion</td>
                <td>$candidato->intereses</td>

            </tr>
                
        @endforeach
</table>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Tras todo esto, al consultar la vista me aparece el siguiente mensaje de error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Alguno me podría orientar un poco? La verdad que esto me parece imposible de realizar si no cuento con un entorno de consola, ¿no creen?

`.ENV`

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=trabinnova_laravel
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=*******
```

Comment: Tu pregunta es muy amplia y basada en opiniones lo cual generará su cierre, pero te diré si es posible, usa a Laravel como un api

Comment: Como utilizo laravel como api?

Comment: Investiga cómo hacer una api restful

Comment: Sé trabajar con laravel. Lo que no sé es como "mezclar" drupal con laravel

Comment: @Alexander ya te dijeron como podria ser, laravel de [api](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-resources)

Comment: @BetaM he actualizado la pregunta

Comment: @JuanRivera he actualizado la pregunta

Comment: @JuanRivera he probado con las combinaciones App\Candidato, App\Models\Candidato, app\models\candidato... etc etc jajajaj

Comment: @Alexander entonces la duda no tiene nada que ver con la *integración* de Drupal con Laravel si no con una carga fallida de una clase modelo

Comment: @BetaM La duda principal era la integración de Drupal con Laravel y una visto tus comentarios pues procedí a utilizar Laravel como API. Ahora mi duda es esta :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema estaba en el fichero del modelo `Candidato`. El namespace que estaba utilizando era `App` cuando debería de ser `App\Models`